# How to preserve initial state on change of input value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code, simply want to update the text value on input field change.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const Form = () => {
    const initialState = {
        name: 'John',
        age: 25
    };
    const [{ name, age }, setFormState] = useState(initialState);

    const handleNameChange = (e) => {
        setFormState({
            name: e.target.value
        });
    };

    const handleAgeChange = (e) => {
        setFormState({
            age: e.target.value
        })
    };
    
    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                <label htmlFor='name'>Name: </label>
                <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder={name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
                <p>The person's name is {name}.</p>
                <br />
                <label htmlFor='age'>Age: </label>
                <input type='text' id='age' name='age' placeholder={age} onChange={handleAgeChange} />
                <p>His/her age is {age}.</p>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

A working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-tskj9?file=/Form.js

Problem is, when input a value in the name field, age field is cleared, vice versa. I understand that this might be due to the `initialState` is no longer valid after change in the field, but how can I preserve the values in one `<input>` and `<p>` while input in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could fix it by including the other property in `setFormState`, eg:

```
setFormState({
    name: e.target.value
    age,
});
```

Functional components are not class components - feel free to separate values out into separate variables if they're not related. This'll make the syntax a lot easier:

```js
const Form = () => {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('John');
    const [age, setAge] = React.useState(25);

    const handleNameChange = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleAgeChange = (e) => {
        setAge(e.target.value);
    };
    
    return (
        <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
            <label htmlFor='name'>Name: </label>
            <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder={name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
            <p>The person's name is {name}.</p>
            <br />
            <label htmlFor='age'>Age: </label>
            <input type='text' id='age' name='age' placeholder={age} onChange={handleAgeChange} />
            <p>His/her age is {age}.</p>
        </form>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Comment: For separating values out, what if there are many states, it would be cumbersome to write `useState` for too many times?

Comment: If you have a large number of values (like 6+), perhaps - separate states wouldn't be so DRY, but it'd still be more semantic IMO. At that point, feel free to choose whichever seems better, it's probably opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

In `useState` hook the properties are not merged as it used to be in `setState` function within class components. You will have to include the missing fields, to keep them in the object.

```
setFormState({
   name: e.target.value,
   age,
});
```